# Javascript copy <p> tag with html format to clipbord

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to copy all of the content from a p tag using javascript. It works, but it copies the text in one long line of text. I want it to copy with the format using the break tags, like if someone were to copy / paste using their mouse like so:

Current Time: :

Time Found: :

Ambient Temp: °C

Notes:

Frequency:

Reproducible?"

Thanks so much for any help.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>title</title>
      </head>
      <body> 
      <h2>Documentation Sheet</h2>

     <p id="p1">
     Current Time: :<br>
     Time Found: :<br>
     Ambient Temp: °C<br>
     <br>
     <br>
     Notes:
     <br>
     <br>
     Frequency:<br>
    Reproducible? 
     </p>

      <button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p1')">Copy text</button>

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

      </body>

      <script>

      function copyToClipboard(element) {
      var $temp = $("<input>");
      $("body").append($temp);
      $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
      document.execCommand("copy");
      $temp.remove();
    }
      </script>
    </html>ere
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One can write a function to do this like:

```
function copyToClipboard(id) {
        var from = document.getElementById(id);
        var range = document.createRange();
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        range.selectNode(from);
        window.getSelection().addRange(range);
        document.execCommand('copy');
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
 }
```

Note: My solution does not require jQuery, and takes a document id as an input, so don't forget to leave out the "#"!

Just use it as follows:

```
 <button onClick="copyToClipboard('p1')">Copy text</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a quick and easy way to do what you want to do. You'd have to use `html()` instead of `text()` to extract the contents of the `<p>` tag, but then you'd have a bit of work to do processing the HTML you'd get back -- stripping tags that should be ignored, converting entities, converting inner `<p>` and `<br>` into line breaks, etc.

So you'd change this line like this:

```
$temp.val(parseHtml($(element).html())).select();
```

Then would follow the harder work of defining the `parseHtml()` function.

Comment: OK, I have to admit that sheeldotme's solution is better than mine. I didn't know about those very useful "range" functions!